# Remove cache from assembly location during uninstall

Tags: dll, installation, vsto, add-in, shadow-copy

I have created an Office addin and windows installer application for it.
According to [this](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/how-do-i-programmatically-find-the-deployed-files-for-a-vsto-add-in/) article, addins dll'a are copied to directory like this `C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\VBJZ5WH8.6NJ\HRZA3JXN.LVG\b0520efe\3a5b99ef_2e21cb01\GoldMail Outlook Add-In.DLL`. I wish to remove those copied files during the uninstall process. Could sb please tell me how to get the full path to those copied files in `C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\` in my installer application (actually in uninstall)? Is it saved in registry or in any other location? I have noticed, it even happens, the files are copied multiple times. Any help would be appreciated, greetings.

Comment: office will clean up files from this location, why would you like to poke in?

Comment: It seems like it happens that it doesn't. Especially when I have a new version of an addin. Generally I was also interested whether whose IDs are somewhere writen? One dll is allways saved in the same named folder (like 3a5b99ef_2e21cb01), but I can't find any references to this number.